# Package docker maven application and run it using a shell script

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am building Scigraph database on my local machine and trying to move this entire folder to docker and run it, when I run the shell script on my local machine it runs without error when I add the same folder inside docker and try to run it fails

Am I doing this right way, here's my DOckerfile

```
FROM goyalzz/ubuntu-java-8-maven-docker-image
ADD ./SciGraph /usr/share/SciGraph
WORKDIR /usr/share/SciGraph/SciGraph-services
RUN pwd
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ['./run.sh']
```

when I try to run it I'm getting this error

```
docker run -p9005:9000 test
/bin/sh: 1: [./run.sh]: not found
```

if I run it using below command it works

`docker run -p9005:9000 test -c "cd /usr/share/SciGraph/SciGraph-services && sh run.sh"`

as I already marked the directory as WORKDIR and running the script inside docker using CMD it throws error

Comment: did you try adding `run.sh` script with `ADD` command in Dockerfile?

Comment: @baris.aydinoz run.sh is already in WORKDIR, I updated question with new details, you can check those. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scigraph as provided in their ReadMe, you can to run mvn install before you run their services. You can set your shell to bash and use a docker compose to run the docker image as shown below

Dockerfile

```
FROM goyalzz/ubuntu-java-8-maven-docker-image
ADD ./SciGraph /usr/share/SciGraph
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
WORKDIR /usr/share/SciGraph
RUN mvn -DskipTests -DskipITs -Dlicense.skip=true install
RUN cd /usr/share/SciGraph/SciGraph-services && chmod a+x run.sh
EXPOSE 9000
```

build the scigraph docker image by running

```
docker build . -t scigraph_test
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  scigraph-server:
    image: scigraph_test
    working_dir: /usr/share/SciGraph/SciGraph-services
    command: bash run.sh
    ports:
     - 9000:9000
```

Answer (score 0):

give / after SciGraph-services and change it to "sh run.sh" ................  and look into run.sh file permissions also

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your `run.sh` doesn't have the `#!/bin/bash` header, so it cannot be executed only by running `./run.sh`. Nevertheless, always prefer to run scripts as `/bin/bash foo.sh` or `/bin/sh foo.sh` when in docker, especially because you don't know what changes files have been sourced in images downloaded from public repositories.

So, your `CMD` statement would be:

```
CMD /bin/bash -c "/bin/bash run.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the shell and the executable to the CMD array ...

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "./run.sh"]
```